# Sorting multiple lists to get a single organised list

Tags: python, automation, dataset

I have multiple lists with coordinates:

```
x = [2423, 2342, 4432]
 
y = [532, 5432, 5432] 

w = [7456, 256, 5645] 

h = [2345, 6543, 8764]
```

I want to concatenate these lists so that the position of an item would correspond with the position of other items in a single list. You can think of it as a dataset for every item in x, y, w, h with the same position in the same list

for example:

```
Boxes = [
[x[0],y[0],w[0],h[0]],
[x[1],y[1],w[1],h[1]],
[x[2],y[2],w[2],h[2]],
]
```

Of course I would not write manually the position of an element for every list, but this shows what I want to achieve.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `list(map(list, zip(x, y, w, h)))` or `[list(i) for i in zip(x, y, w, h)]`

Comment: You are not looking for *sorting* but rather *zipping* from multiple lists here. ^^^ answer is above.

Comment: I will take it into account, and thanks for sharing your knowledge with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the coordinates dynamically, you can append them into the boxes one by one using the for loop with the length of the x. Please note length of all arrays should be the same.

```py
x = [2423, 2342, 4432]
y = [532, 5432, 5432] 
w = [7456, 256, 5645] 
h = [2345, 6543, 8764] 

Boxes = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    Boxes.append([x[i], y[i], w[i], h[i]])
```

After this `Boxes` value would be equal to that:

```py
[[2423, 532, 7456, 2345], [2342, 5432, 256, 6543], [4432, 5432, 5645, 8764]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatviely, you try to do this by List Comprehension in *zip*ping way:  (it's prob. more efficient for big lists... and don't have to use *index* to access each item in lists.)

Inspired by @Mechanic... sharing the credit?  ;-)

```py
x = [2423, 2342, 4432]
y = [532, 5432, 5432] 
w = [7456, 256, 5645] 
h = [2345, 6543, 8764] 
    
Boxes = []

Boxes = [[a, b, c, d] for a, b, c, d in zip(x, y, w, h)]
print(Boxes)

# OR as @Mechanic suggested and posted earlier, you can try this too (even more *elegant* and *less typing*): 

outs = [list(tp) for tp in zip(x, y, w, h)]    # tuple for all 4 items
```

Comment: It's a bit strange to unpack tuples and build lists in the same order. I prefer to use `list` directly for tuples before unpacking ;-)

Comment: Totally agreed. But it's stated earlier already. And it's really for the *beginner* .. ;-)